# Docker и Genymotion как помирить и заставить работать эмулятор по виндой?

Tags: android, windows, docker, genymotion

Установил на винду Docker. После этого эмулятор Android Genymotion перестал работать. При запуске я вижу ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после этого в VirtualBox образ который запускался не закрывается(пишет "Останавливается").

Стандартный эмулятор в Android Studio при этом запускается.

При установке докера я включал Hyper-V проблема в этом?

Возможно ли вообще помирить софт и заставить работать?

UPD: стандартный эмулятор в Android Studio первый раз запустился но больше не работает(чёрный экран при запуске).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При включенном Hyper-V просто не работают х64 виртуалки VirtualBox. Это факт и никак не фиксится. В случае с WMware ситуация не понятная. Одни пишут что у них работает, у других - нет.